# Mediation analysis in mixed model ordinal logistic regression

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, mediation, ordered-logit

For my thesis i want to perform a mediation analysis in a mixed model ordinal logistic regression.

y             = survey data (ordinal variable)
x             = year (2021 data compared to 2020 data)
mediator (m)  = discrete count data

Data is clustered per school, and individual

I have looked into andrew hayes process macro, but this is not suitable for clustered/multi-level data. Are there any options for SPSS to run this analysis?

Thank you for reading my question!

kind regards,
E

Comment: Look into the R package `lavaan`: https://lavaan.ugent.be/

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have looked into it and it indeed looks promising. Unfortunately I am not familiar with R since my institution works with SPSS. Would such an analysis be possible in SPSS ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. R is free (as opposed to SPSS). There are lots of tutorials online. The other possibility is the software MPlus. It's harder to use than lavaan, and has a license fee, but it's been around a lot longer. It's possible that someone at your institution uses MPlus - if anyone does a lot of SEM analyses and factor analyses, they should be familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.